# Calling the same instance of JFrame from different JFrames

Tags: java, swing, jframe

How do I call the same instance of a JFrame say A from 5 different JFrames if I need the display of A to be updated every time I call it??

Comment: use `setVisible(boolean flag)`.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to provide a reference to the frame to each of the 'child processes' and a public method that will update the UI.

Or since it is better not to *extend* JFrame, a utility class that has a *reference* to the JFrame and provides the public method.

---

BTW: Most apps. would have only a single JFrame.  The way to handle the situation you describe might be better implemented using JDialogs or JOptionPanes for the 'secondary' windows.  Or to collect all the GUI elements together into the main frame: JDesktopPane/JInternalFrames, CardLayout, JTabbedPane..